# Python "speech_recognition" library throwing error ``audio_data`` must be audio data with the following audio

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

Here is my code in which I'm getting the audio:

```
import soundcard as sc
import soundfile as sf
import speech_recognition as sr

OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "out.wav"    # file name.
SAMPLE_RATE = 48000              # [Hz]. sampling rate.
RECORD_SEC = 5                  # [sec]. duration recording audio.

with sc.get_microphone(id=str(sc.default_speaker().name), include_loopback=True).recorder(samplerate=SAMPLE_RATE) as mic:
    # # record audio with loopback from default speaker.
    data = mic.record(numframes=SAMPLE_RATE*RECORD_SEC)
```

Now the following is the code to which I'm sending the above audio labelled as "data":

```
r = sr.Recognizer()

# loop through audio stream and transcribe in real-time
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(data, language='en-US',
                                show_all=False, key=None)
    print(text)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

In the above soundcard package it takes the audio playing on your speakers output and convert back it as mic input.

I've tried the above code and many approaches similar to the above one but it is continuously throwing back the error that "audio-data" must be audio data or "the source must be an audio source"...

Comment: I _think_ what's happening here is that the mic isn't picking up from the speakers properly. Have you adjusted the value of `r.energy_threshold` to adjust the sensitivity of the microphone? Is the value of `r.energy_threshold` the default?

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem because when I save a ".wav" file and then convert(speech to text) it with speech recognition module then it works fine but If I try to do a direct or live conversion(speech to text) then it always comes up with an error.

Comment: OK, have you ruled out problems like Python having access to the stream - that is, the Python process has access to the location where the stream is stored?